# Caption an SVG with <text> element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I am new to working with SVGs. I am trying to caption an svg of a person with that person's name. Here is my attempt:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 258.75 258.75" style="enable-background:new 0 0 258.75 258.75;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
<circle cx="129.375" cy="60" r="60"/>
<path d="M129.375,150c-60.061,0-108.75,48.689-108.75,108.75h217.5C238.125,198.689,189.436,150,129.375,150z"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="60" y="75">Person Name Here</text>
</g>
</svg>
```

When I try to anchor the text below the image the text disappears. how do I

1. Change the size of the image?
2. Leave space at the bottom of the image for the person's name?

Here is the snippet:

```js
var svg = '<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"viewBox="0 0 258.75 258.75" style="enable-background:new 0 0 258.75 258.75;" xml:space="preserve"> <g> <circle cx="129.375" cy="60" r="60"/><path d="M129.375,150c-60.061,0-108.75,48.689-108.75,108.75h217.5C238.125,198.689,189.436,150,129.375,150z"/><text text-anchor="middle" x="60" y="75">Person Name Here</text></g></svg>'

$('#name').append(svg);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="name">Hello</p>
```

Comment: Two questions: (1) What is an "SVG of a person"? Are these photos you're captioning? If so, you should use JPEGs instead. (2) What is preventing you from using [`<figcaption>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_figcaption.asp) elements in your HTML markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be what you need:

1. You can change the size of the image with css, it will scale all your svg.
2. You just need to give some more space to the viewBox and position your name accordingly.

Hope this helps, snippet:

```js
var svg = '<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"viewBox="0 0 258.75 350.75" style="enable-background:new 0 0 258.75 258.75;" xml:space="preserve"> <style>.style1 {font-size: 15px;} </style> <g> <circle cx="129.375" cy="60" r="60"/><path d="M129.375,150c-60.061,0-108.75,48.689-108.75,108.75h217.5C238.125,198.689,189.436,150,129.375,150z"/><text class="style1" text-anchor="middle" x="125" y="290">Person Name Here</text></g></svg>'

$('#name').append(svg);
```

```css
svg, object {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="name">Hello</p>
```